# How to join several tables in a selection (Ef core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a database model:
[image]

Tables "Product" and "Attributes" are not related. But each product can have a list of attributes.

In order to send the client a list of products with attached attributes and values, I implement the logic:
API Controller method:

```
[HttpGet("get")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
  var productList = await _db.Product
    .Include(p => p.Category)
    .Include(p => p.ProductType)
    .Take(25)
    .ToListAsync();

  var productListJson = await HandleProductEntities(productList);

  return Ok(productListJson.ToString());
}
```

And the method that forms the product json-object with attributes:

```
private async Task<JArray> HandleProductEntities(IEnumerable<Product> productList)
{
  if (productList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(productList));
  var productListJson = new JArray();
  foreach (var productEntity in productList)
  {
    var attributesList = await _db.ProductAttributeValues
      .Where(pav => pav.ProductId == productEntity.Id)
      .Select(pav => new
      {
        Id = pav.AttributeValue.Attribute.Id,
        Name = pav.AttributeValue.Attribute.Name,
        DisplayName = pav.AttributeValue.Attribute.DisplayName,
        Value = pav.AttributeValue.Value,
        ValueDescription = pav.AttributeValue.Description
      }).ToListAsync();

    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
      ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
    var productJson = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productEntity, jsonSerializerSettings));

    var attrArrayJson = JArray.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attributesList, jsonSerializerSettings));
    foreach (var token in attrArrayJson)
    {
      var paramName = (string) token["name"];
      if (paramName == null)
      {
        throw new NullReferenceException();
      }

      productJson.Add(paramName, token);
    }

    productListJson.Add(productJson);
  }

  return productListJson;
}
```

**But this logic is overloaded. There is probably an easier way to get products with attributes from the database using EF core. Can someone tell me how to do it right?**

I tried to do this:

```
var resultTest = from productAttributeValue in _db.ProductAttributeValues
  join attributeValue in _db.AttributeValue on productAttributeValue.AttributeValueId equals attributeValue.Id
  join product in _db.Product on productAttributeValue.ProductId equals product.Id
  join attribute in _db.Attribute on attributeValue.AttributeId equals attribute.Id
  select new
  {
    Name = product.Name,
    Attribute = attribute.Name,
    AttributeValue = attributeValue,
  };
```

But it’s impossible to group attributes for each product.

Answer (score 0):

```
from product in _db.Product
join pav in _db.ProductAttributeValues on product.Id equals 
productAttributeValue.ProductId into productAttributeValueList
from productAttributeValue in productAttributeValueList.DefaultIfEmpty()
join attributeValue in _db.AttributeValue on productAttributeValue.AttributeValueId equals attributeValue.Id
join attribute in _db.Attribute on attributeValue.AttributeId equals attribute.Id
select new 
{
    Name = product.Name,
    Attribute = attribute.Name,
    AttributeValue = attributeValue
}
```